# OWC11 in Delphi 11.2 Alexandria - Access Violation on TPivotTable.Create

Tags: delphi, segmentation-fault, access-violation, delphi-11-alexandria, office-web-components

We now receive an access violation when creating an instance of the TPivotTable class. This has always worked in previous Delphi versions without issue.

Steps to reproduce:

Import the type library for OWC11 (Office Web Components).

Create an instance of TPivotTable.

An access violation will occur.

Breaking on that exception in the debugger, we're at Line 837 in Vcl.OleCtrls, seems to have to do with license checking perhaps.

LicKeyStr does look suspiciously bogus to me. "My run-time license key" However, this is the same when building in previous Delphi versions (particularly Berlin where we're migrating from) and nothing breaks. It works there, but not with the new compiler in Alexandria.

This doesn't seem to be caused by anything special in our application code. I can reproduce it in a standalone program that does nothing but try to create the pivot table object.

I am spinning my wheels a bit on this and time is of the essence. Any suggestions for a possible cause or fix here would be greatly appreciated.

To summarize, I expected to be able to import the type library for OWC11 fresh in the new Delphi 11 IDE and have everything work as usual. But instead, we immediately segfault when creating an instance of TPivotTable.

Comment: When you Import the type library for OWC11 is import made for 32 bit or 64 bit OWC11?

Comment: It should all be 32-bit. I am doing identical steps in both Delphi versions I have available, and running a 32-bit test application. (For clarification, re-importing the type library in the older Delphi, as a sanity check, it still works fine.) [We have had some bugs to squash in 64-bit apps related to newly-default compiler flag for high entropy ASLR in Delphi 11, but I figured this was totally unrelated to that sort of thing, being a 32-bit application.]

Comment: Have you compared imported library created by newer and older Delphi versions. Finding out what the difference is between them might help you solve your problem.

Comment: I thought I remembered doing that previously, but for the good measure I went ahead and re-imported in both versions to compare the diff. The PAS files generated are identical other than the date stamp comment. Still only the older one runs without error.

Comment: If PAS files are identical I suggest you also try to use PAS file generated in older Delphi version in newer Delphi version and vice versa. If PAS file from older Delphi will also work in newer Delphi then there is some other difference than just date stamp that you have overlooked. But if PAS file from older Delphi also fails in newer Delphi then the cause may lie elsewhere. Perhaps newer Delphi has different compiler settings.

Comment: Thank you. The answer did end up being a different linker option rather than in the generated code. Delphi 11 has apparently several, rather than the one I knew about, newly defaulted compiler/linker options. This one in particular (NXCompat/DEP) is hidden and disabled in older Delphi, while it is enabled and visible in Delphi 11.

Comment: Interesting! So your application was being blocked by Windows Data Execution Prevention mechanism when NXCompat/DEP option was enabled. Was this logged in Windows Event log? If I remember correctly there is a specific section of event log just for DEP prevention. In case if this was logged it would not be a bad idea to report this to Embarcadero as potential bug. If I understand the meaning of this option it should make executable which is much more secure.

Comment: Hm... I notice now that it only logs in the Event Viewer when executed without the debugger attached, but yes, the Application Error is logged now that I run it cold. (It's not obvious that DEP is involved just from the logged error though.) This is mainly for my curiosity. We plan to turn this flag back on soon after the offending code is replaced with something that doesn't rely on this ancient OWC. It seems like a good thing to keep it on, but since it was always off in the past for this app, any issue it may be preventing is not new and is therefore not an emergency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the immediate cause (although I am unsure why it breaks things).

Delphi 11 has enabled the NXCompat (DEP) linker flag by default, which is actually not presented in the linker options at all in previous Delphi versions (where it is disabled by default).

It's listed under "Prevent Data Execution compatible" in the linker options. Disabling it prevents OWC from blowing up the application.

We'll simply have to live without this for the short term.